# UITextFields are not positioned correctly in my iPad.....Why?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I added two UITextFields programmatically in my app but the positions of them are not correct on the iPad. On the iPhone there are where I want them to be but for the iPad they are positioned not where I want them to be. How do I get them to be positioned the same as the iPhone?

```
    textFieldOne.frame = CGRectMake(80, 120, 160, 40)
    textFieldOne.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line
    textFieldOne.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    textFieldOne.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.Yes
    textFieldOne.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
    textFieldOne.delegate = self
    textFieldOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    textFieldOne.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    textFieldOne.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
    self.view?.addSubview(textFieldOne)


    textFieldTwo.frame = CGRectMake(80, 210, 160, 40)
    textFieldTwo.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line
    textFieldTwo.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    textFieldTwo.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.Yes
    textFieldTwo.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
    textFieldTwo.delegate = self
    textFieldTwo.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    textFieldTwo.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    textFieldTwo.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
    self.view?.addSubview(textFieldTwo)
```

Comment: can you show screen shot of result you getting and where you want to positioned them?

Comment: There to the left and top on my ipad. On the iphone there in the middle of the screen one on the top and one on the bottom.

Comment: Ill post a screenshot if you need to see it.

Comment: is this work in iphone all devices like (iphone 5, iphone 6,& iphone 6+ ) i don't think that it will work in all the iphone devices??

Comment: Post both screenshots iPhone and iPad.

Comment: no the 6 plus and 4s there the same as the ipad. Just the 5s,5 and iphone 6 its right.

Comment: Yes it happend because you did not add any constraint to your text field and iPhone and iPad have different screen sizes and you are testing this in iPhone 5s which is showing it into center but if you test this on iPhone 6 then you will get different result too. @coding22

Comment: I added the textfields programmatically in spritekit. How do I set the constraints there?

Comment: http://imgur.com/bGDPFzO,WZ45yOe#0       the first one is for the iphone and the second pic is the ipad.

Comment: how about dynamically setting the x and y with respect to some other UIelements or according to the screen width or the `self.view` property which changes according to device width

Comment: You are using autolayout ?

Comment: Try this `textFieldOne.center=CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height*0.3);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will work perfect.

```
var X : CGFloat = 0;
    var Y : CGFloat = 0;
    var Width : CGFloat = 0;
    var Height : CGFloat = 0;
    var ScreenWidth : CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width;
    var ScreenHeight : CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height;

    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad
    {
        // for ipad.
        X = (ScreenWidth * <X position you want in ipad>) / 768;
        Y = (ScreenHeight * <Y position you want in ipad>) / 1024;
        Width = (ScreenWidth * <width you want in ipad>) / 768;
        Height = (ScreenHeight * <height you want in ipad>) / 1024;
    }
    else
    {
        //for iphone.
        X = (ScreenWidth * <X position you want in iphone 5>) / 320;
        Y = (ScreenHeight * <Y position you want in iphone 5>) / 568;
        Width = (ScreenWidth * <width you want in iphone 5>) / 320;
        Height = (ScreenHeight * <height you want in iphone 5>) / 568;
    }
```

Above code make your frame just pass it to in CGRectmake method and you got perfect UI.

hope this will help you.

Comment: Can you help me translate it to Swift? Im having trouble understanding it. Thanks!

Comment: OK i will try to converting.

Comment: @coding22 I'm converting hope this is help you a lot just put this before you giving your textfield frame.

Comment: and don't forget to add x,y,width,height which you want in calculation in replace <> and put size and position which you want.

Comment: @coding22 if it will help you thant please accept my answer and if not than tell me.

Comment: Sorry my bad was playing around with the values. For the 4s and 6+ its not  positioning correctly for me.

Comment: have you added a splash screen for those devices?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88653/discussion-between-jay-raparka-and-coding22).

Comment: The height and width shouldn't be a fixed size based on iPhone or iPad. Please use measurements based on UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

Answer (score 2):

This way you can add constraint programatically and it will center your `textFields` horizontally.

```
    textFieldOne.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line
    textFieldOne.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    textFieldOne.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.Yes
    textFieldOne.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
    textFieldOne.delegate = self
    textFieldOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    textFieldOne.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    textFieldOne.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
    textFieldOne.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view?.addSubview(textFieldOne)

    //center it horizontally
    let horizontalConstraintForFirst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textFieldOne, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraintForFirst)

    //top space
    let topConstraintForFirst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textFieldOne, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: topLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 120)
    view.addConstraint(topConstraintForFirst)

    //width
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textFieldOne, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 160)
    textFieldOne.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

    //height
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textFieldOne, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)
    textFieldOne.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

    textFieldTwo.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line
    textFieldTwo.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    textFieldTwo.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.Yes
    textFieldTwo.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
    textFieldTwo.delegate = self
    textFieldTwo.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    textFieldTwo.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    textFieldTwo.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
    textFieldTwo.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view?.addSubview(textFieldTwo)

    //center it horizontally
    let horizontalConstraintForSecond = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textFieldTwo, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraintForSecond)

    //top space
    let topConstraintForSecond = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textFieldTwo, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: topLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 210)
    view.addConstraint(topConstraintForSecond)

    //width
    let widthConstraintForSecond = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textFieldTwo, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 160)
    textFieldTwo.addConstraint(widthConstraintForSecond)

    //height
    let heightConstraintForSecond = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textFieldTwo, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)
    textFieldTwo.addConstraint(heightConstraintForSecond)
```

**UPDATE:**

For SpriteKit replace this lines:

```
let topConstraintForFirst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textFieldOne, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: topLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 120)
view.addConstraint(topConstraintForFirst)

let topConstraintForSecond = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textFieldTwo, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: topLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 210)
view.addConstraint(topConstraintForSecond)
```

(which is giving you and error) With this line:

```
//top space for first TextField
self.view?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textFieldOne, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 120))

//top space for second TextField
self.view?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textFieldTwo, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 210))
```

Comment: I get an error for topLayoutGuide it says "use of unresolved identifier "topLayoutGuide"

Comment: Yes Im adding textFields to the GameScene.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88654/discussion-between-coding22-and-dharmesh-kheni).

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are setting their frame origin position to be the same on all of the devices. That is 80 units to the right of the screen and 210 units from the top. On iPhone, it might look centered but on an iPad with a bigger screen its not. Try to change it into something like this if you want to avoid adding constraints programatically:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width

textFieldOne.frame = CGRectMake(80, 120, 160, 40)
textFieldOne.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2, 120)
(...)

textFieldTwo.frame = CGRectMake(80, 210, 160, 40)
textFieldTwo.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2, 120)
(...)
```

or

```
textFieldOne.frame = CGRectMake(80, 120, 160, 40)
textFieldOne.frame.origin.x = screenWidth/2 - (textFieldOne.frame.width/2)
(...)

textFieldTwo.frame = CGRectMake(80, 210, 160, 40)
textFieldTwo.frame.origin.x = screenWidth/2 - (textFieldTwo.frame.width/2)
(...)
```

or...

```
textFieldOne.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/2 - 80, 120, 160, 40)
(...)

textFieldTwo.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/2 - 80, 210, 160, 40)
(...)
```

Comment: I tried the second code and for the iphone and it works but on the ipad the end of the rectangles dont show its just two lines, one on the bottom and one on the top.

Comment: Post a screenshot or something. The code isn't magic and it should work as expected, something else must be happening.

Comment: give me one sec ill post a screen shot now.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinate system of iPhone and iPad devices start from Top Left corner
meaning top left corner = x-0,y-0. So your x and y of the textfield may look that it is in the center but actually it is hardcoded for x = 80 and y = 120 for the first one. Where an iPhone has a width of `320 (iPhone4,5)`,`375 (iPhone6)`,`414 (iPhone6+)` and a iPad has a width of `768 points.`

Comment: you want every device condition?

Comment: by setting the x and y according to `self.view` and some old school math, we dont have to set condition for every device width

Comment: See my answer Do you suggest this kind of framing?

Comment: making so many if statement is a downside right away and is not a good practice as, you have mentioned only for iphone5, as u go on and add for iphone 6 and 6+ the if statement increase. This kind of conditions for a single outlet is discouraged.

Comment: just put it is not only for iphone 5 it's a ratio based on screen size. go through my calculation.

Comment: isnt this more helpfull? 
`CGRect frame = CGRectMake:(x,y,self.view.frame.size.width  *widthScale ,self.view.frame.size.height * heightScale)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88649/discussion-between-jay-raparka-and-saheb-roy).